# Prestashop shipping cost by state

Tags: prestashop

Is there by any chance a way to set shipping cost by state in a carrier in prestashop?

i.e. let's say i want a different shipping cost to send in Alabama than in Alaska with the same carrier

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this. You can purchase an external module, such as [this one](http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/shipping-modules/83-localized-shipping.html), or create an override [like so](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/160695-solved-carrier-by-postcode-the-easy-way/):

1) Copy "classes/Address.php" to "override/classes/Address.php".

2) In line 28 change class name from AddressCore to Address

3) Before function getZoneById, paste this new function

```
/**
* Return postcode of address
*
* @param $id_address Address id
* @return integer postcode
*/
public static function getPostcodeByAddress($id_address){
    $row = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
    SELECT `postcode`
    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'address a
    WHERE a.`id_address` = '.(int)($id_address));
    return $row['postcode'];
}
```

4) Add before first line of function getZoneById this:

```
$postcode=self::getPostcodeByAddress($id_address); 

if(in_array($postcode,array(your list of postcodes))){
    return id-of-your-zone;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Go to Localization->Zones
2. Created new different Zones according to State. eg. Zone name = "NSW"
3. Go to Localization->States
4. Choose state and change it's new zone. eg. "New South Wales" now changed into "NSW" zone.
5. Go to Shipping->Carriers
6. Click on "Edit" on shipping method.
7. Click on "Shipping Locations and Costs"
8. Now change shipping cost by each zone which has now related states.