# Does Prestashop support shipping by zip-code?

Tags: prestashop

I've spent the last two days checking on every portion of Prestashop, trying to figure out how to restore zip-code based shipping functionality, and at the very least, install a flat-rate shipping fee so we don't get gouged by our own website.

I checked various websites, and found very little help; the only responses I see say things about the difficulty.

I tried using modules for shipping and tested out their demos but was just as confused by them, and getting the same errors (in cart, it says any area code is not a region that can be shipped to).

Here's my original thread: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/460500-shipping-carriers-deleted-shipping-functionality-caput-urgent/

Comment: I create custom zones , and each zone associate its zip code in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027122/prestashop-shipping-cost-by-state